# Distribution upgrade problem

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10. 
I have executed the terminal command :

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

I've got the following error : 
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic_3.8.0-35.52~precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/lib/modules/3.8.0-35-generic/kernel/mm/hwpoison-inject.ko', which is also in package linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic 3.8.0-35.50
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.8.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.8.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic_3.8.0-35.52~precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get dist-upgrade` does not upgrade the OS to the latest release. It acts very much like `apt-get update`, in addition to handling changing dependencies with new versions of packages.

If you want to upgrade to a new release, use `do-release-upgrade` instead. (I recommend you first switch to runlevel 1 with `init 1`, however.)

Relevant excerpt from the manual:

```
   upgrade
       upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on
       the system from the sources enumerated in /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently
       installed with new versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no
       circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages not already
       installed retrieved and installed. New versions of currently installed packages that
       cannot be upgraded without changing the install status of another package will be left
       at their current version. An update must be performed first so that apt-get knows that
       new versions of packages are available.

   dist-upgrade
       dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently
       handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart"
       conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages
       at the expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade command may
       therefore remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of
       locations from which to retrieve desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5)
       for a mechanism for overriding the general settings for individual packages.
```

---

**EDIT**

Following Nasreddine's comment, I looked into it further and it seems others have had the same problem as evidenced by [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1276428) launchpad bug report.  The [7th post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1276428/comments/7) by Andreas Tj seems to offer a plausible solution but I can't say whether it works, since I don't have this particular problem and thus can't test it.

Comment: same problem, I've encountered the same error message !

Comment: @Nasreddine: try the steps described by Andreas Tj (last post) in the following launchpad bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1276428

Comment: Thanks @miguelg, I have ignored the problem by upgrading the system using the terminal command "sudo do-release-upgrade"